# awk transpose lines with removing duplicate column based on pattern with 4th column break after

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, row, multiple-columns, transpose

hi i am in process transpose this multi lines 
input and transpose those to

```
nickname jeff site A site_out out 9C:02:24
nickname jeff site A site_in in 9C:02:24
nickname jeff site A in DOOR_SECT_X1 68:01:40
nickname jeff site A in DOOR_SECT_A1 68:01:10
nickname david site B site_in in EA:A7:D3
nickname david site B in EXT_MAT-G 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C in EXT_MAT-H 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C in ARR_N1D 68:01:10
nickname martin site C in ARR_N2D 68:01:10
nickname geoff site A site_out out 00:C9:AB
nickname geoff site A site_in in 00:C9:AB
nickname geoff site A in DEF_DOOR_ARR 80:07:E6
```

this output

```
nickname jeff site A 
site_out out 9C:02:24
site_in in 9C:02:24
in DOOR_SECT_X1 68:01:40
in DOOR_SECT_A1 68:01:10
nickname david site B 
site_in in EA:A7:D3
in EXT_MAT-G 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C 
in EXT_MAT-H 80:16:7B
in ARR_N1D 68:01:10
in ARR_N2D 68:01:10
nickname geoff site A 
site_out out 00:C9:AB
site_in in 00:C9:AB
in DEF_DOOR_ARR 80:07:E6
```

where duplicated "nickname" along with second column like e.g. martin / geoff is removed and kept only once, and on each 4th column is done break to next line

i stucked here with this code returning below

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2 FS$3 FS$4 FS; a[k]=a[k] FS $NF}
   END {for(k in a) print k  "\n" a[k]}' 

nickname david site B
 EA:A7:D3 80:16:7B
nickname geoff site A
 00:C9:AB 00:C9:AB 80:07:E6
nickname martin site C
 80:16:7B 68:01:10 68:01:10
nickname jeff site A
 9C:02:24 9C:02:24 68:01:40 68:01:10
```

thank you for hints how to move with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Perl one-liner

```
$ cat ya801.txt
nickname jeff site A site_out out 9C:02:24
nickname jeff site A site_in in 9C:02:24
nickname jeff site A in DOOR_SECT_X1 68:01:40
nickname jeff site A in DOOR_SECT_A1 68:01:10
nickname david site B site_in in EA:A7:D3
nickname david site B in EXT_MAT-G 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C in EXT_MAT-H 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C in ARR_N1D 68:01:10
nickname martin site C in ARR_N2D 68:01:10
nickname geoff site A site_out out 00:C9:AB
nickname geoff site A site_in in 00:C9:AB
nickname geoff site A in DEF_DOOR_ARR 80:07:E6

$ perl -lane ' $y=join(" ",@F[0..3]) ; $z=join(" ",@F[4..$#F]); if ($x ne $y) { print "$y\n$z";$x=$y } else { print "$z";} ' ya801.txt
nickname jeff site A
site_out out 9C:02:24
site_in in 9C:02:24
in DOOR_SECT_X1 68:01:40
in DOOR_SECT_A1 68:01:10
nickname david site B
site_in in EA:A7:D3
in EXT_MAT-G 80:16:7B
nickname martin site C
in EXT_MAT-H 80:16:7B
in ARR_N1D 68:01:10
in ARR_N2D 68:01:10
nickname geoff site A
site_out out 00:C9:AB
site_in in 00:C9:AB
in DEF_DOOR_ARR 80:07:E6

$
```

Comment: please consider upvoting the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with this script:

You need to know when to stop printing consecutive nicknames: that's the `$2 != nickname` condition. When that is true, it prints the nickname and the remaining columns (that's `print_data` function) and "skip" to the next line in the file (that's `next`)

The `print_data` function prints all remaining columns after the nickname part. If you add more columns at the end of the line, you shouldn't need to change that script.

```
BEGIN {
  nickname = ""
}

function print_data() {
  for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
    printf "%s ", $i
  }
  print ""
}

# change "$2" if you add more column before nickname
$2 != nickname {
  nickname = $2
  print $1, $2, $3, $4
  print_data()
  next
}

{
  print_data()
}
```

Comment: hi @customcommander, customcommander, thank you, could you please give me brief explanation for those lines? e.g. where to change it if i will add one more column before nickname, that will help me , br ya801

Comment: thank you, played with it a bit and it works on many columns i want